# Viewing data in the VSCode variable explorer requires pandas

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

Create a variable like so:

```
ls = list([0, 3, 5])
```

View the list by clicking the <kbd>dataviewer</kbd> button

Error Message reads `Python package 'pandas' is required for viewing data`

`pandas` is installed in the current environment. Why does this fail?

Comment: There might be multiple installations of Python on your system. The instance VSCode is using may not have pandas.

Comment: Thanks you @Samik. The one that my code is using definitely has `pandas`. Similarly my base installation. How can one identify which  one is VSCode using?

Comment: For me clicking the python version in the status bar shows all the instances. I put a screenshot below.

Comment: The [official docs on environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) also explains how to select your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a back and forth yesterday with the extension devs in GitHub. It seems that the version.release string of `pandas` I was using includes characters that are not correctly parsed by the extension.

They mentioned that it was going to be addressed yesterday in the Insider version. Looking forward to validating.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but maybe someone will find his/her way to this thread as I did.

What solved this issue for me, was the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77858582/23382601).

The problem seems to happen due to a wrong handling of a warning. When I installed pyarrow in the active environment, everything worked again:

```
conda install pyarrow
```

or

```
pip install pyarrow
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the instance by clicking the Python version in the status bar.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the python version that is used for the variables

1. open settings:
2. search for: Python › Data Science: Variable Queries
3. edit the json:

```
"python.dataScience.variableQueries": [
        "C:\\Users\\Faramarz\\anaconda3\\envs\\data-class\\python.exe"
]
```