# Visual Studio Code gives error when using Data Viewer: "Python package 'pandas' is required for viewing data"

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am running a python notebook in VS Code (see image). It runs fine but when I try to inspect a dataframe with the Data Viewer I get:
`"Python package 'pandas' is required for viewing data."`

The package is installed, otherwise, the code would not work and the data frames would not be present in the variable panel. When I click on "Install" I get: `"Error: All data science packages require an interpreter be passed in"`

I only have two environments, Anaconda and one created by VS code. I have tried selecting either one and nothing changes, code runs on both and I get the same errors on both.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

[image]

EDIT: The previous question [Viewing data in the VSCode variable explorer requires pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029128/viewing-data-in-the-vscode-variable-explorer-requires-pandas) does not solve my issue. As mentioned above I have selected different environments without fixing it.

EDIT 2: Updating pandas did not fix it either. It was only solved by updating Anaconda, as suggested by Mrinal Roy.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062052/8840245) on the same issue claimed it was fixed around a year ago. If not, then you probably have an older version of Anaconda or VS Code. Otherwise, what version of pandas do you have in both conda environments? VS Code Data Viewer requires pandas package 0.20 or later. Try upgrading to the latest and check.

Comment: Fantastic. It is solved. I tried updating pandas and that didn't work. Then I updated all anaconda packages and that did the trick. How do I upgrade your comment to an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viewing data in the VSCode variable explorer requires pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029128/viewing-data-in-the-vscode-variable-explorer-requires-pandas)

Comment: @AB-NeuroDynamic-Software I have updated my comment as an answer as per your request above.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt No, that old answer did not answer my question. I had read it before posting my own question. My problem was solved by Mrinal Roy's suggestion to update the Anaconda package. This was not a previously posted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer on a similar issue Viewing data in the VSCode variable explorer requires pandas mentioned it was fixed around a year ago.

> It seems that the version.release string of pandas I was using includes characters that are not correctly parsed by the extension. They mentioned that it was going to be addressed yesterday in the Insider version. Looking forward to validating.

So, you probably have an older version of Anaconda or VS Code. Otherwise, what version of pandas do you have in both conda environments? VS Code Data Viewer requires pandas package 0.20 or later. Try upgrading it and related packages to the latest and check.

Answer (score 1):

What solved this issue for me, was the answer i found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77858582/23382601

there seem's to be a wrong handling of a **warning**. when installed *pyarrow* in the active environment, everything worked again:

```
conda install pyarrow
```

or

```
pip install pyarrow
```