# vscode pandas version 0.20.0 required for viewing data Error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can't use data viewer in VScode as an error requiring pandas version 0.20.0 or above comes up.

I am using VScode and conda environments on a mac m1. I used a new environment with pandas, scikit learn etc but when I try to use data viewer I get an error saying pandas version 0.20.0 is required. Installing from there makes no difference and printing pandas version to screen shows that it is running 2.0.3. Downgrading pandas makes no difference and i still get that error. I am aware that this has been a bug and I think it maybe now but I'm unsure where in my process it resides - this is what i need help with. I'm new to digging around like this. i don't know what else to do.

If I run an old environment created under an older conda version then everything runs as normal and data viewer works fine. Installing scikit-learn (which wsn't in the. old env) didn't cause the pandas error to come up. I would use this however, I cannot access my pickle data file which was saved using a newer version. There are a lot of conflicts with trying to update the environment to a newer pandas.

I am also getting a warning

```
Intel MKL WARNING: Support of Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) enabled only processors has been deprecated. Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library 2025.0 will require Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.
```

when I run my code which may or may not be related.

This is my jupyter log for the new environment if it helps.

```
Visual Studio Code (1.81.1, undefined, desktop)
Jupyter Extension Version: 2023.7.1002162226.
Python Extension Version: 2023.14.0.
Platform: darwin (arm64).
14:58:37.322 [info] User belongs to experiment group 'FastKernelPicker'
14:58:37.322 [info] User belongs to experiment group 'NewRemoteUriStorage'
14:58:37.322 [info] User belongs to experiment group 'PasswordManager'
14:58:37.322 [info] User belongs to experiment group 'NewJupyterSession'
14:58:38.239 [info] Start refreshing Kernel Picker (1694440718239)
14:58:38.253 [info] Using Pylance
14:58:43.585 [info] End refreshing Kernel Picker (1694440718239)
14:58:59.475 [info] Process Execution: ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python -m pip list
14:59:50.126 [info] Found debugAdapterPython on Debug Configuration to use
14:59:50.164 [info] Process Execution: ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python -c "import pandas;print(pandas.__version__)"
15:01:10.224 [error] [Error: Python package 'pandas' version 0.20.0 (or above) is required for viewing data.
    at tP.promptInstall (~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:24:601008)]
15:01:10.228 [warn] DataScience Error [Error: Python package 'pandas' version 0.20.0 (or above) is required for viewing data.
    at tP.promptInstall (~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.7.1002162226-darwin-arm64/out/extension.node.js:24:601008)]
15:01:19.813 [info] Ending debug session 7f3759e6-c428-4aa5-b3e8-ac017a77fa34
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by installing pyarrow in the respective venv, e.g:

```
pip install pyarrow
```

Hypothesis on why this is needed:

- If pyarrow is not installed, newer versions of pandas may give a warning when initializing, that pyarrow is not found, while it will be a dependency for pandas going forward (>3.0)
- It could be that the Jupyter notebook extensions is not handling this warning message well and thinks pandas is not properly installed. It then installs pandas and shows the correct preview of variables. But when trying to open the next variable, it will again get the same warning message as pyarrow will still not have been installed and the error box pops up again.

Answer (score 0):

From your error log it seems like you are doing this from a debug session. The debugger, however, uses the general interpreter/environment specified VSCode-wide. Maybe the environment/interpreter where you are trying to fix the problem is a different one than that one?

Possible concrete explanations of what might be happening:

- Perhaps you are in a specific virtual environment (e.g. using Conda) within your active terminal where you are trying to install pandas, which is different from the environment the debugger uses.
- It may also be that you are using a Jupyter kernel with associated virtual environment and are trying to install pandas there using e.g. `!pip install pandas`, again into an environment different from the one the debugger uses.

Therefore, changing the general interpreter (Ctrl+Shift+P > then type Python: Select Interpreter) to one that has a recent enough version of pandas installed may solve the issue.

Alternatively, install pandas in the environment that is currently used by the debugger. You can do this to activate the environment before installing.

In the [original issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/14332) from last year this was not brought up as a possible solution and the issue has since been closed, so I cannot comment on it there. Perhaps this answer here can help people who stumble on the same thing.

Another answer that is related with the same possible solution: [VSCode: There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993566/vscode-there-is-no-pip-installer-available-in-the-selected-environment)